# Ebean Finder joins @OneToMany fields in a strange way (4 results instead of 2)

Tags: sql, jpa, playframework, annotations, ebean

I have a method in my Model class which queries DB with the help of Finder:

```
public static List<Bet> getBetsByUser(User user){
    System.out.println("ROW COUNT: "+ find.fetch("user")
            .fetch("moneyPoolEntity.account")
            .fetch("coupon.moneyPoolEntities.account")
            .fetch("moneyPoolEntity.bettingTable")
            .fetch("moneyPoolEntity.moneyPoolType.currency").setDistinct(true)
            .where().eq("user", user).findRowCount() );
    List<Bet> betList = find.fetch("user")
            .fetch("moneyPoolEntity.account")
            .fetch("coupon.moneyPoolEntities.account")
            .fetch("moneyPoolEntity.bettingTable")
            .fetch("moneyPoolEntity.moneyPoolType.currency").setDistinct(true)
            .where().eq("user", user).findList();
    System.out.println("LIST COUNT: "+betList.size());
    for(Bet b : betList){
        System.out.println(b.id+" b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = " + b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size());
        for (MoneyPoolEntity mpe : b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities){
            System.out.println("mpe--"+mpe.id+" ; account: "+mpe.account.id);
        }
    }
    return betList;
}
```

Useful to say that there is 3 entities in each **coupon.moneyPoolEntities** list.
So, in case size of the output is 1, everything is fine and I have:
.findRowCount() = 1
betList.size() = 1
while .coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = 3
and manual SQL querying returns table:
[image]
with all equal fields except **MoneyPoolEntity.id** and **Account.id**. So Ebean is able to pack 3 entities into .coupon.moneyPoolEntities list.

PrintLn result looks like:

```
ROW COUNT: 1 
LIST COUNT: 1
243 b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = 3
mpe--201 ; account: 241
mpe--203 ; account: 243
mpe--202 ; account: 242
bets.size() = 1
```

The problem arrives when I add one more Bet entity still with 3 entities in **coupon.moneyPoolEntities** list.

SQL query result looks like:
[image]

But now instead of two Bet entities each with **coupon.moneyPoolEntities** of size 3 Ebean packs it in a very strange way:

PrintLn result:

```
ROW COUNT: 2
LIST COUNT: 4
261 b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = 2
mpe--202 ; account: 242
mpe--203 ; account: 243
243 b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = 2
mpe--202 ; account: 242
mpe--203 ; account: 243
261 b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = 2
mpe--202 ; account: 242
mpe--203 ; account: 243
243 b.coupon.moneyPoolEntities.size() = 2
mpe--202 ; account: 242
mpe--203 ; account: 243
bets.size() = 4
```

WHY?

Comment: Can you please post your models code and the code? I can't get to how your models references each other and to the db tables on screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. For some reason PostgresDB was sometimes returning sorted table and sometimes not (although I haven't asked to sort it).

The problem is that Ebean in my case joins correctly only if the table is sorted.

So, the workaround that works for me is the addition of **.orderBy("id")** to the fetch sequence.

Comment: Note that you should not need to add the orderBy() in that Ebean should do that automatically.  For future note that it is good to include the Ebean version and generated sql in questions like this.  It is also good to ping the Ebean google group to ensure someone looks at the issue.  Cheers, Rob.