# Ebean parses the first bean correctly and the rest not

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a oneToMany relationship between two entities, ie. hotel has many rooms. When I use a fetch("rooms") in ebean the first entity is filled correctly with its children while the others appear "repeated". ie, hotel 1 -> room1, room2 and then I get the second entity hotel2 -> room3 , hotel2-> room4, hotel2 -> room5.

Much in the same fashion as this question [Ebean Finder joins @OneToMany fields in a strange way (4 results instead of 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068478/ebean-finder-joins-onetomany-fields-in-a-strange-way-4-results-instead-of-2) I debugged ebean and seeing how the checkForDifferentBean() method in CQuery.java works I understand how sorting the parent entity helped him. This has not helped me though. I am also using postgresql.

The ctx.getPersistenceContext() call for the first bean works, starting with the second the context goes empty, making checkForDifferentBean() return true.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a close look at the ebean code, I realized this problem arised due to a bug in the framework. I fixed it and opened a pull request https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/pull/426/files

Comment: For reference - this was logged as issue https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/425 ... fixed in 6.9.1

Comment: hey, instead of adding it as a comment you can add as answer and ill acccept it

Comment: Note that I did add it as an answer but moderators deleted it - sad.

Comment: thats weird i remember you answered it, it was not me who deleted it

Comment: Yes, I see it the deleted answer in pink (I doubt anyone else sees it) ... and can see the moderators that didn't like it as an answer. Hmmm, I might just try again and see what happens (maybe with better wording).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to a bug with findIterate() and how the root beans are added to the persistence context in that case.

This is fixed in version 6.9.1 of Ebean and was logged as issue #425.

Refer to https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/425 for the test case, commit and extra details.

Cheers, Rob.